# Using HAVING to filter based on the sum of a nested model in Sequelize Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a data structure in Postgres like the following:

**Donations**

```
id  amount  status
1   5000    OK
2   7500    OK
```

**Donation Items**

```
id  donationId  amount  includeInTotals
1   1           2500    false
2   1           2500    false
3   2           7500    false
```

In pseudo SQL I'm trying to do something like:

`SELECT * FROM donations 
    WHERE SUM(SELECT donation.items WHERE "donationId" = "donations"."id" 
    AND "includeInTotals" = false) >= "donations"."amount"`

Essentially wanting to remove donations where the total of the "includeInTotals = false" donation items is the same as the donation value.

This is the code I've got so far for Sequelize:

```
Models.donations.findAndCountAll({
   where: { status: 'OK' },
   include: {
        model: Models.donation_items,
        as: 'items',
        duplicating: false,
    },
   having: sequelize.literal('COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN "items"."includeInTotals" = false THEN items.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) < "donations"."amount"'),
   group: ['"donations.id"', '"items.id"']
});
```

This is working for **donation ID: 2** – it's not returned by the query, but **donation ID: 1** is, despite the two amounts equaling 5000.

Is there something wrong I'm doing with SUM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the GROUP clause here was joining the donation items and returning an incorrect SUM, so I switched to a sub-query in the WHERE clause. I added this to my `where` which worked for me!

```
amount: {
        $gt: globals.sequelize.literal(`
            (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0) FROM donation_items
            WHERE "donation_items"."includeInTotals" = false
            AND "donation_items"."donationId" = "donations"."id")
        `),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer an actual query which should work, which is half the answer:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM Donations d1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT donationId, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM DonationItems di
    WHERE includeInTotals = false
    GROUP BY donationId
) d2
    ON d1.id = d2.donationId AND d1.amount = d2.amount
WHERE
    d2.donationId IS NULL;
```

While this doesn't touch your Sequelize problem, having the correct raw query is a total prerequisite to doing anything in PHP which will bear fruit later on.  There are other, more efficient, ways we could write this query, but the above version would probably be easiest to integrate into your PHP code.